# Rate of change in regards to water.

Tags: calculus

I am just wondering would be the correct approach to these types of questions?

### Question:

Two containers are filled up with water at different speeds. 
At any time $t ≥ 0$ the speed with which the heights of the water levels increase in the
two containers is given by the following two functions

$f(t) = (t^2 + 5t)\,e^{-t}$
$g(t) = (2t ^2 + 3t)\,e^{-t}$

(a) At what times $t \ge 0$ do the water levels increase equally fast and at what
times is $f(t) > g(t)?$

(b) Find and classify the critical points of $g(t)$ on the interval $(0, \infty).$

(c) Use integration to find the area enclosed by the curves $y = f(t)$ and
$y = g(t)$ between $t = 0$ and $t = 2.$

### Possible ways

**A**:you would need to sub in zero? I find that it wouldn't work but cannot seem to understand how would you answer this.

**B**: Just plug in the values to solve..  ?

**C**: Chain rule would sufficient here?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

For (a), solve $f(t)=g(t)$ for $t.$ For (b), set $g(t)=0,$ solve for $t$, and use First or Second Derivative Test to find out whether they are local minima, local maxima, or points of inflection. For (c), compute $$\displaystyle\int_0^2|f(t)-g(t)|\,dt.$$